# Why CircleAvator's position can't align exactly under The IconButton?

Tags: flutter, flutter-positioned, iconbutton

*created a IconButton and positioned it responsively. And then  wrapped it with CircleAvator widget.*
I was expecting the circleavator would be placed under the IconButton and also would behave responsively but CircleAvator doesn't align under the button even doesn't act responsively. 
**Here is my code-**

```
Positioned(
                    left: (_width / 2.4) - (_height / 3.5 * 0.30),
                    top: (_height * 0.5) / 2.35,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: colorBlack,
                      radius: 50.0,

                      child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                          iconSize: _height / 3.5 * 0.5,
                          color: loading ? Colors.teal : Colors.red,
                          onPressed: doConversion),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Here is my output of Device -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoehM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stack 2 Widgets there is actually an easier solution. Just use the `Stack` Widget.
You can use `alignment` to position the element within the Stack.

```
 Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            radius: 50.0,
          ),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
              iconSize: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      )
```

[image: Before]
[image: Using Stack]

Answer (score 0):

Actually when using the `CircleAvatar()` as the parent, it covers the child widget to a certain size and as the child gets more size than a certain amount (about 70%) it cant wrap the child as expected and starts shifting the child to bottom right. And also the `IconButton()` has a preset padding about 6 or 8 which  you can set it to 0 by defining the padding property yourself like this `padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),`. So addition to the @Benedikt J Schlegel answer I suggest 2 more shots you can try:

1. Set the `IconButton()` padding to 0 and never pass the child a size more than 170% of the parent:

   ```
           Positioned(
               left: (_width / 2.4) - (_height / 3.5 * 0.30),
               top: (_height * 0.5) / 2.35,
             child: CircleAvatar(
               backgroundColor: Colors.black,
               radius: 100.0,

               child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                 child: IconButton(
                     icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
                     padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                     iconSize: 170,
                     color: Colors.red,
                     onPressed: (){}
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
   ```
2. User a `Container()` as the parent of the `IconButton()`:

   ```
     Positioned(
       left: (_width / 2.4) - (_height / 3.5 * 0.30),
       top: (_height * 0.5) / 2.35,
       child: Container(

         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: Colors.black,
           shape: BoxShape.circle,
         ),

         child: IconButton(
             icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
             iconSize: 100,
             color: Colors.red,
             onPressed: (){}
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ```